# Python - Created an .exe and the result is not showing up

Tags: python

I've created a code in python which is a simple random name generator, transformed to .exe.

The exe file executes, but when I answer input prompts the app finishes without any result.

the .py and the setup code which created the .exe version of my code are below:

```
#name-gen

import random

#name length selection

char_name_lenght = input

print(input('How long charater name you would like to have? (1 or 2 words)? '))

name_module1 = ('Lil', 'Geek', 'Jucy', 'Odin'+chr(39)+'s', 'Thor'+chr(39)+'s')
name_module2 = chr(46)
name_module3 = ('dog', 'hammer', 'warfare')
name_module4 = name_module3

first = random.choice(name_module1)
second = name_module2
third = random.choice(name_module3)

if char_name_lenght == 2 :
    name = (first + second + third)

elif first == ('Odin'+chr(39)+'s') :
    name = (first + " " + third)
elif first == 'Thor'+chr(39)+'s' :
    name = (first + " " + third)

else :
    name = random.choice(name_module4)

print('Your name is: ' + name)
```

```
#setup for exe

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None    

if sys.platform== 'win32':
    base = None

executables = [Executable('rand_nm_gen.py', base=base)]

packages = ['idna']
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "<any name>",
    options = options,
    version = "<any number>",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: As an aside, you can use `\'` or enclose your string in `" "` instead of using `chr(39)` :)

Comment: Also, the reason it closes immediately is because the program finished... Instead of `print`, use `input` for the final statement... Basically, your program ended by printing the text to the screen, and then closed afterwards, as there were no more functions, etc running...

Comment: thanks, it resolved :)